How to view the conversations happening via WhatsApp Channel in Azure Communication Services
I have created a WhatsApp Channel on Azure Communication Services using my own mobile number.
Is there a way I can see the conversations happening via that Channel, like if someone is sending messages to that channel and receiving automatic replies via backend, where can I see these conversations?
I believe ACS doesn't allows us to associate the number with WhatsApp if that number is getting used in ACS.
Couldn't find anything in the official MSFT documentation.

One option I can think of is to maintain the conversation history at client's end and have your own front-end displaying those convesations (just like WhatsApp). Not sure if there is any out of the box functionality.
